# Spinlock code using atomic_flag in C++ is not compiling in Mac

Tags: c++11, concurrency, spinlock

I tried to write a simple Spinlock code in C++ but the code is not getting compiled in the Mac but is compiling on other gcc compilers.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<atomic>
using namespace std;

class SpinLock 
{
    public:
        atomic_flag flag;
        SpinLock() : flag(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT) {}
        void lock()
        {
            while(flag.test_and_set());
        }
        void unlock()
        {
            flag.clear();
        }
};

SpinLock spin;

void critical_section()
{
    spin.lock();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    spin.unlock();
}

int main()
{
    thread t1(critical_section);
    thread t2(critical_section);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

I tried checking version of clang installed in my machine at the version is:
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.4.0
Thread model: posix

Can any one help me in the fact that why code is not getting compiled?

Comment: What does the compiler error say?

Comment: spinlock.cpp:10:27: error: expected expression
        SpinLock() : flag(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT) {}
                          ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/atomic:2850:26: note: expanded from macro 'ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT'
#define ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT {false}
                         ^
1 error generated.

Answer (score 0):

`atomic_flag (const atomic_flag&T)` is a deleted constructor, and STL defines only two constructors for the `atomic_flag` (another one is default).
`ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` usually doesn't even refer to a value to feed the constructor with, it's just a macro to call some kind of default initialization (for MSVC it's defined as curly brackets `{}`). You may want to initialize your flag like this:

```
class SpinLock 
{
    public:
        atomic_flag flag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
        SpinLock() {}
...
```

Comment: I tried implementing as you suggested but this time I am getting another error. spinlock.cpp:9:28: error: non-aggregate type 'std::atomic_flag' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
        atomic_flag flag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

Comment: @MrigankPrasoon I'll double-check it later on with clang, but essentially default constructor should initialize the instance with `ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` value and you can just use `atomic_flag flag {}`, but I don't think it's part of standard.

Comment: I think there was an issue with the Code Runner extension in VS code. I specifically used g++ spinlock.cpp and it got compiled. Thanks for the help.